# How to have a vector with class elements, some of them with constructor argument assigned?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I want to have something like that, or rather have a vector with elements of a class and change some of them assigning the argument of the constructor:

```
#include <vector>

class lou_reed
{
    int K;

public:
    lou_reed() {
    }

    lou_reed(int arg) : K(arg) {
    }
};


void changeEL(std::vector<lou_reed> & vec, int a, int b, int c) {
    lou_reed aus(c);
    for (int i = a; i < b; ++i) {
        vec[i] = aus;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<lou_reed> velvet_underground(4);
    changeEL(velvet_underground, 2, 3, 6);
}
```

Are there any other better solutions?

Comment: That for loop should be a `std::copy` call. You should also be passing by reference if you want to change it.

Comment: Please indent your code. (And you're missing a `using namespace std;`.)

Comment: `void changeEL(vector <lou_reed> vec,int a,int b, int c){` should be `void changeEL(vector <lou_reed>& vec,int a,int b, int c){` otherwise you are only assigning to a copy of your vector. Apart from that what's wrong with this solution? Hard to suggest a better solution when it's not clear what you think is wrong with this one.

Comment: @jhon I ask if there's a better solution (faster or more concise) to have a final vector like in the code.

Comment: @gx_ - no, the code was **not** missing `using namespace std;`. It was missing `std::` qualifiers on members of `std`. Sledgehammers are never an appropriate tool for writing code.

Comment: @PeteBecker You are right (of course), but considering that OP wasn't even able to indent its code properly, asking for adding `std::` qualifiers seemed to me like asking too much. (Also, this is not a "real" code but a simple example self-contained in a single source file (no headers), so the using directive is ok.)

Comment: But I should probably warn: @TommasoFerrari _Don't_ write "using namespace std;" (or "using namespace _whatever_;" or even something like "using std::cout;") in a _header_ (e.g. file.h, file.hpp, file.hxx, file.hh ...). And even in a source file (e.g. file.cpp, file.cxx, file.cc ...) it's better to avoid it at global scope (or namespace scope), and rather use it only inside a function body, to limit its effect.

Answer (score 0):

in your example `void changeEL(vector <lou_reed> vec,int a,int b, int c){` should be declared as

```
void changeEL(vector <lou_reed>& vec,int a,int b, int c){
                               ^
```

otherwise you are only assigning to a copy of your vector.

---

To achieve what you want you might use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>`:

```
vector <lou_reed> velvet_underground;
void changeEL(vector <lou_reed>& vec,int a, int b, int c)
{
  std::vector<lou_reed> v(b-a, lou_reed(c));
  vec.copy(v.begin(), v.end(), vec[a]);
}
```

I think the class is simplified* however in some cases you might need [assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29) defined for your class `lou_read`

```
class lou_reed {
int K;
public:
lou_reed(){}

lou_reed(int arg):K(arg){
}

lou_read& operator=(const lou_read& other){
   if (this != &other){ // protect against invalid self-assignment
       K=other.K;
       //...deep copy (maybe some pointers in your class ?)
   }
 return *this;
}
};
```

*-as David Rodriguez-dribeas noticed in this particular example you don't need to provide `operator=` the implicitly defined one will do the right thing, I just want to bring into attention that there are cases when this is required

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Can you explain deeper the fact of a possible invalid self-assignment? In which cases could it happen?

Comment: vec[i] = vec[i] , it might not hurt you or it might, for sure this shoud be no op, as this should means nothing

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong in this proposed solution. From the bottom: you don't need to provide `operator=` the implicitly defined one will do the right thing (and will expand to *all* fields if you decide to add them later without having to maintain the extra useless code). The type in question has no need to protect from self aliasing either. The implementation of `changeEL` is unnecessarily **expensive**, as you create a new vector with as many elements as the original (for no good reason) and then copy from it. There is also a typo, you probably meant `&vec[a]`)

Comment: this is what I said "I think the class is simplified, in general if a class is slightly more complicated you will need assignment operator". And in implementation  there is only (b-a) elements in new vector, as needed

Comment: @computer: Most of my classes are far more complicated, and I rarely need to overload assignment. Complexity is not the criteria, the problem with this sort of recommendation is that the user will take that as *truth* and blindly apply it. I have an int and a vector... that is clearly more complex: rewrite assignment manually!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I need to overload assignment sometimes, I have changed the answer to reflect that this is only in "some cases", please review it

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas and regarding your hint about performance of copying the vector, well I think this is not ultra low latency HFT system, OP just want to make it work and this is how he can do it